# Add sticky header to scroll view

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to add a header to a scroll View that is sticky when Vertically scrolled but scrolls regularly when scrolled horizontally.

```
<ScrollView
 directionalLockEnabled = {false} horizontal = {true} maximumZoomScale = {1} scrollEnabled = {true} minimumZoomScale = {.45} zoomScale = {1}
 onScroll = {this.handleScroll}
 scrollEventThrottle = {100}
 stickyHeaderIndicies = {[0]}
 >

<FlatList
contentContainerStyle = {{flexGrow: 1}}
style = {{height: 2000}}

           data = {this.state.data}
           ItemSpeparatorComponent = {this.renderSeparator}
           keyExtractor = {(x, i) => i.toString()}
           onEndReached = {this.loadMoreData}
           onEndReachedThreshold = {0.1}

           renderItem ={({item}) =>

               <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                  <View style = {{width:100, height: 100}}>
                  <Text style= {styles.itemText}>
                      {item.inletThread}
                  </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style = {{width:115, height: 100}}>
                  <Text style= {styles.itemText}>
                      {item.manufacturer}
                  </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style = {{width:165, height:100}}>
                  <Text style= {styles.itemText}>
                      {item.testPressure}
                  </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style = {{width:182, height: 100}}>
                  <Text style= {styles.itemText}>
                      {item.workingPressure}
                  </Text>

                  </View>

                  <View style = {{width:80, height: 100}}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.SampleFunction.bind(this, item)}>
                  <Text style = {{textAlign: 'center', paddingTop: 25, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 25}}>Click here</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
               </View>
           }
           ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.renderSeparator}
           ListHeaderComponent = {this.renderHeader}
           stickyHeaderIndicies = {[0]}
       />
  </ScrollView>
```

This renders the header fine but it does not stick to the top of the screen when scrolling in either direction. I have gotten it to work sort of by putting the header in the scroll view and syncing the two scroll views x components but this method is very slow because of state calling.

If anybody has another method I could try that would be great.

Comment: have you found the answer to that @paulgiordan?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is to late but for every one else that search for this question here is a github project that i fund (it's not mine) : [GitHub Link](https://github.com/amarjain07/StickyScrollView)

Answer (score -2):

Use { Header } from native-base.

Import that from native-base library

You can go through the documentation right here :- 
https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase

Comment: This is an app-level nav bar component, and is not what OP asked for.  They're asking for a header to a ScrollView, which doesn't necessarily mean that the ScrollView is the top-level component in the app, which is the only time this element would be relevant to the problem.